# How to Send/receive Data via bluetooth android phone to medical equipment having bluetooth

Tags: android, bluetooth

I want to connect my android phone with the a medical equipment via Bluetooth.At one time i want to connect with 3 devices and continuously getting the data from one device and sent to the another also stored in the SD card.

Also the data are in different formats like hex and octal. So Is it possible and is there any API to do that ?
Provide me some link or any code is appreciated.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/BluetoothHDP/index.html

Answer (score 1):

I found a very nice page regarding this topic.
http://www.ars2000.com/Bluetooth-IEEE-11073.html

Answer (score 1):

Antidote is an open IEEE 11073 stack that works in Android too: http://oss.signove.com/index.php/Antidote:_IEEE_11073-20601_stack

A sample app for Android, based on Antidote:
https://github.com/brasileiroaraujo/HealthServiceAndroid